# Apply stylesheet

Tags: css, stylesheet

I have this bootstrap html code

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm   navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Our Service
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Call</a>
          </li>
           <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a>
            </div>
          </li> -->
          </ul>
          <div class="social-part">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I want to add stylesheet in the below line to make the text "Home" look white. Kindly help.

`<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>`

Kindly help me to apply stylesheet in the above line to make the test look white. I need to apply white color on this.

Comment: `<a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color: white;">Home ...`

Comment: Kindly tell me common code for all the link.

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap there is a class that makes your text white just add .text-white to the link. See [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/colors/).

Answer (score 0):

Add on your Home text-light. I change the background to dark so the home to be visible

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark  navbar-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Our Service
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">service 3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Call</a>
          </li>
           <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a>
            </div>
          </li> -->
          </ul>
          <div class="social-part">
            <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks Tzimpo for the help

Comment: @RahulKumar No problem! Can you upvote and set it as answer for your question?